# Add classes to latest previously clicked element

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css

I have a calendar that looks like this, and its styled using Tailwind CSS:
[image]

8 Wednesday is currently clicked, and that's why it has a pink background and pink shadow. 7th was the previously clicked element, and that's why it has only the pink shadow (I removed the pink background class, but kept the pink shadow).

What I want is to keep the latest previously clicked element so I could add the pink shadow, but only to the latest element, not all previously clicked elements.

This is how my JavaScript code looks like:

```
//select needed elements from HTML
const calendarDates = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable')
const dateDisplay = document.getElementById('show-details');
const selectedDateDayElement = document.getElementById('selected-date-day');
const selectedDateElement = document.getElementById('selected-date');

let latestClicked = null;
let latestPreviouslyClicked = null;

// if there is no date, dont add hover efects
for (let i = 0; i < calendarDates.length; i++) {
    if (calendarDates[i].textContent.trim() === '') {
        calendarDates[i].classList.remove('hover:bg-pink-500', 'hover:shadow-md', 'hover:cursor-pointer', 'hover:shadow-pink-500');
        calendarDates[i].classList.add('empty')
    }
}

// select only elements that are not empty
const clickableDates = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable:not(.empty)');


clickableDates.forEach(dateElement => {
    dateElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const dateValue = dateElement.textContent.trim();
        const year = 2017;
        const month = 1;

        if (latestClicked !== null) {
            latestPreviouslyClicked = latestClicked;
            latestClicked = null;
            latestPreviouslyClicked.classList.remove('bg-pink-500');
        }

        dateElement.classList.add('bg-pink-500', 'shadow-md', 'shadow-pink-500');
        latestClicked = dateElement;

        const selectedDate = new Date(year, month, parseInt(dateValue));

        const daysOfWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
        const dayOfWeek = daysOfWeek[selectedDate.getDay()];

        selectedDateDayElement.textContent = dayOfWeek;
        selectedDateElement.textContent = dateValue;

        dateDisplay.style.display = 'block';
    });
});



// Close the date details when clicked outside, and this works at it should
document.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('clickable')) {
        clickableDates.forEach(element => {
            element.classList.remove('bg-pink-500');
        });
        dateDisplay.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

The problem that I'm facing is that it keeps the shadow for all the previously clicked elements:
[image]

The expected behavior is:

- I click on date A - it gets pink background and shadow ('bg-pink-500 shadow-md shadow-pink-500')
- I click on date B - it gets pink background and shadow, date A has only shadow
- I click on date C - its gets pink backgrounds and shadow, date B has only shadow, date A doesn't have any extra classes added.

Comment: why 2 variables for the previously clicked element? `latestClicked` and `latestPreviouslyClicked`, shouldn't one variable be enough?

Comment: i was testing different methods to achieve what i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I also misread your question.

The problem is in the part

```
        if (latestClicked !== null) {
            latestPreviouslyClicked = latestClicked;
            latestClicked = null;
            latestPreviouslyClicked.classList.remove('bg-pink-500');
        }
```

You are actually just removing the background from the `latestClicked` element, never removing the shadow styles.

This should work:

```
if(latestPreviouslyClicked !== null) {
  latestPreviouslyClicked.classList.remove('shadow-md', 'shadow-pink-500');
}
// update second latest element after changing the classes
latestPreviouslyClicked = latestClicked;
if(latestClicked !== null) {
  latestClicked.classList.remove('bg-pink-500');
}
latestClicked = dateElement;
```

The important part is to mutate the element before reassigning it to the next element.

Or, if [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) works in your environment (bundler or only new browsers supported):

```
latestPreviouslyClicked?.classList.remove('shadow-md', 'shadow-pink-500');
// update second latest element after changing the classes
latestPreviouslyClicked = latestClicked;

latestClicked?.classList.remove('bg-pink-500');
latestClicked = dateElement;
```